# PHP Submission form not sending all fields?

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to build a contact form for a real estate website, and the submission works. However when it gets to my e-mail address, for some reason, the "Tenants" and "Landlords" fields are empty. Am I missing something? See:

```
<?php 
$action=$_REQUEST['action']; 
if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */ 
    { 
    ?> 
 <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit"> 
    First & Last Name:<br> 
    <input name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> <br>
    Your Email Address:<br> 
    <input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> <br>
    Tenants, please describe what you're looking for:<br> 
    <textarea name="tenants" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br> <br>

    Landlords, please describe what you're looking for:<br> 
    <textarea name="landlords" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br> <br>

          Additional Comments:<br />
        <textarea name="message"></textarea>
        <br>
        <center>
    <input type="submit" value="Send email"/> </center>
<br /></p>
    </form> 

 <?php 
    }  
else                /* send the submitted data */ 
    { 
   $name=$_REQUEST['name']; 
   $email=$_REQUEST['email']; 
   $tenants=$_REQUEST['tenants'];
   $landlords=$_REQUEST['landlords'];

   $message=$_REQUEST['message']; 
    if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message=="")) 
        { 
        echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again."; 
        } 
    else{         
        $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email"; 
        $subject="Leasing Submission"; 
        mail("myemailhere@test.com", $subject, $message, $from); 
        echo "Email sent!"; 
        } 
    }   
?>
```

Comment: You're not including the POST data in the body of your `mail()`

Comment: They're not empty - you're never sending them in the first place.

Comment: Plus, do consider using [proper **header( )** information](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try this:

```
else                /* send the submitted data */ 
{ 
$name=$_REQUEST['name']; 
$email=$_REQUEST['email']; 
$tenants=$_REQUEST['tenants'];
$landlords=$_REQUEST['landlords'];

$message=$_REQUEST['message']; 
$fullmessage = " {$name}, mailaddres {$email},tenant info: {$tenants} , landlord info: {$landlords}. He gaves us the following message: {$message}";

if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message=="")) 
    { 
    echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again."; 
    } 
else{         
    $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email"; 
    $subject="Leasing Submission"; 
    mail("myemailhere@test.com", $subject, $fullmessage, $from); 
    echo "Email sent!"; 
    } 
}   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually sending the landlords or tenant data. You're taking the fields in and you're assigning them to variables, but you're not attaching them to the $message variable, which is what is sent via email.

Try something like:

```
$tenants = $_REQUEST['tenants'];
$landlords = $_REQUEST['landlords'];
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];
$message .= "\n\nLandlords: $landlords\n\nTenants: $tenants";
```

Comment: Assuming OP is using `Content-Type: text/html` therefore `\n` or line breaks would be more suitable.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'll change them to newlines anyway, just because that's the default setup.

Comment: It's always best to show it using that, in conjunction with an OP's posted code, if the header (html) header information is left out. Then the OP might come back and say "I have `<br>`'s in my email". Which stands at opening up a can of worms, as it were. ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I took another glance at his code while I was writing my answer and my eyes caught sight of the HTML he has in his output, which is what made me think he was sending a HTML email. :)

Comment: The HTML as far as I can see is only the form. It can get tricky sometimes ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- He has some embedded in his PHP as well, which is what caught my eye: `echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again.";`

Comment: It has nothing to do with the mail's message body/header. It's only used for verification purposes.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh I know that. I was just saying that the HTML in question caught my eye when I took a quick scan over his question. That's when my brain subconsciously decided that he was sending a HTML email.

Comment: Haha, I know what you mean. I get the occasional brain farts too. After looking at code for 10-12hrs a day at times, does eventually play tricks on one's eyes and mind.